# Repetitive warnings about Github's ECDSA host key differing from the key for IP address

Tags: ssh, git, github

I keep getting this message when using Git with Github:

> Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '20.248.137.48'
> Offending key for IP in /home/steve/.ssh/known_hosts:133
> Matching host key in /home/steve/.ssh/known_hosts:140
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

I'm aware that [Github's SSH host key changed](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/) and have updated my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` to include the new key, and triple checked that there are no other entries for it in that file.

When I update it, the message goes away for a bit (a few hours maybe) then inevitably returns.

It's particularly painful because if I attempt to interact with Github from within VS Code (for instance, pushing a branch), the window hangs, presumably waiting for me to type 'yes' into an invisible terminal.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 on WSL 2 on Windows 10.

Comment: The *RSA* host key changed. The ECDSA and Ed25519 didn't change. This is weird.

Answer (score 1):

When GitHub cycles their keys, it can end up on any number of potential IP addresses.  This is because GitHub uses a whole host and array of servers for their stuff.  There's no way to properly filter *all* of those, so you might want to consider something like this added to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com:
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This is untested but theoretically should disable host key checks when using GitHub.

Comment: This doesn't seem right though. It can't really be the case that Github has a situation where the only sane way to work with it is to disable an important security check. And from my googling, not many other people seem to have this problem?

Comment: @SteveBennett I have it every year or so with Github myself, because their keys change and such.  They also spin up new servers on cloud load balancing and such which does point at different endpoints, etc.  You're right, disabling the check is a bad thing, even if it's *just* for Github.  However, if you don't disable the check for the host you want to use (GitHub) then you'll get the message repeatedly.  There's no way around this getting rid of the notices otherwise.

Comment: Once a year would be fine. But I'm experiencing this every day.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when doing a `git clone` today:

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '140.82.114.3'
Offending key for IP in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:Y
Matching host key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:X
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

(where X and Y are line numbers)

I was confused, because I've definitely pushed to GitHub recently from this computer (i.e. after their RSA host key changed).

I inspected with:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F github.com
```

which gave:

```
# Host github.com found: line X
github.com ECDSA SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
```

Based on [GitHub's posted key fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints), that looks right.

Then I checked the IP address from the error message:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 140.82.114.3
```

This gave:

```
# Host 140.82.114.3 found: line Y
140.82.114.3 RSA SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
```

Here it's using an RSA key, and that *doesn't* match the one from above page.  So this must be GitHub's old RSA key.

I removed it with:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R 140.82.114.3
```

After that `git clone` completed successfully without prompts, so it must have just used the ECDSA key attached to `github.com`.

I'm guessing the cause is I deleted the old RSA key for `github.com`, but it's also stored under each IP address for some reason, so when that server came up in the rotation again it complained.

I don't know of an easy way to automatically get all GitHub IPs, but given the error basically says "the key is wrong for this IP, but it matches for the hostname" I am fine with just deleting the IP entry.

Comment: For the IPs, use https://api.github.com/meta